# Updating state and fetching from API onClick using React Hooks and MapBox

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-map-gl

I have an issue when trying to fetch from API using latitude and longitude when an area of the map is clicked. The initial map load is fine, with data from the API being displayed as expected, and I can confirm that the geoLoc array state is updating onClick, as the console log is showing this. However, for some reason the API is not updating even though the state of both geoLoc.latitude and geoLoc.longitude are changing. Is there any reason for this? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

```
    const Maps = () => {

  const [events, setEvents] = useState([])

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(geoLoc)
    e.preventDefault()
    setGeoloc({ ...viewport })
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://api.list.co.uk/v1/events?near=${geoLoc.latitude},${geoLoc.longitude}/5`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setEvents(res))

    console.log(geoLoc.latitude)

    return () => console.log('Unmounting component')

  }, [])

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    latitude: 51.45523,
    longitude: -2.59665,
    zoom: 13.5

  })

  const [geoLoc, setGeoloc] = useState({
    latitude: 51.45523,
    longitude: -2.59665
  })

  if (events.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return <div>
    <ReactMapGL mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/dredizzle/ck3owxclr138a1cqnzupab2hc"
      {...viewport}
      onViewportChange={viewport => {
        setViewport(viewport)
      }}
      onClick={handleClick}

    >

      {events.map(event => (
        <Popup
          key={event.event_id}
          latitude={event.schedules[0].place.lat}
          longitude={event.schedules[0].place.lng}
        >
        </Popup>
      ))}


      {/* <Popup latitude={51.45523} longitude={-2.59665}>
        <div>event here</div>
      </Popup> */}
      <GeolocateControl
        positionOptions={{ enableHighAccuracy: true }}
        trackUserLocation={false}
      />
    </ReactMapGL>
  </div>
}

export default Maps
```

Comment: Ok so I see now that the issue is (I think)  that I need to actually perform a fetch request every time the map is clicked, as it won't just update automatically. But I have no idea how to to do this with React hooks!

Comment: you need to add the viewport in your useEffect dependencies array

Comment: thanks so much! I had to use the callBack function to fetch the API on click, but it's now working :)